# SQLite usin Sum()-function in a VIEW

Tags: sql, sqlite, view, sum

so i created a view, in this view i have person_id's, account_id's, dates, payment methods and value.
in the payment method i specified two different ones: withdrawal and deposit. withdrawal is shown as a negative value.
what i want to do now is to print out all account_id's where the sum of withdrawals and deposits is negative.

this is my CREATE VIEW code:

```
CREATE VIEW payment
    ( personID, AacountID, date, payment_method, value )
AS SELECT pers_id, acc_id, date, 'deposit', value
    FROM deposit
UNION ALL
SELECT pers_id, acc_id, date, 'withdrawal', -value
FROM withdrawal
```

I am not allowed to use the sum()-function inside the create view statement, i have to use a query on the view to print out all accounts with an overall negative value.
I've been searching for a while now, but i just found how to use the function inside the create view statement.

Comment: What do you mean with "not allowed"? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

> what i want to do now is to print out all account_id's where the sum
>   of withdrawals and deposits is negative

and

> I can't use the sum()-function inside the create view statement

**You can use aggregation inside view:**

```
CREATE VIEW payment 
AS 
SELECT acountID, SUM("value") AS total
FROM (
  SELECT acc_id AS acountID, "value"
  FROM deposit
  UNION ALL
  SELECT acc_id, -"value"
  FROM withdrawal) AS sub
GROUP BY acountID;

SELECT *
FROM payment
WHERE total < 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/91662/2/0)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that using keywords like `date/value` is bad practice. If you really need them qoute them with `"`.

**EDIT:**

> 'i am not allowed to use sum()-function inside the create view statement'

One more trial, use your view and add simple aggregation with post aggregation filtering using `HAVING`:

```
CREATE VIEW payment 
AS 
SELECT pers_id, acc_id AS accountID, "date", 'deposit' AS payment_method, "value"
FROM deposit
UNION ALL
SELECT pers_id, acc_id, "date", 'withdrawal', -"value"
FROM withdrawal;
```

Query:

```
SELECT accountId, SUM("value") AS total
FROM payment
GROUP BY accountId
HAVING total < 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6789a/3/0)**</kbd>

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer, but  i'm sorry because i think i expressed my issue wrong. i changed the 'can't use the sum()-function' to 'i am not allowed to use' now. i think now it's clear.

Comment: @grantelbart See updated. Anyway your question is still a bit unclear for me.